# Should sfValidatorEmail not accept dots at the end of the local part of an email address?

Tags: regex, email, symfony1, symfony-1.4

There was a bug in my application, apparently dots at the end of the local part of an email address where not considered an error and the webservice I was using was telling me the email address was badly formatted.

`sfValidatorEmail` uses this regular expression:

```
const REGEX_EMAIL = '/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i';
```

Dots at the end of the local part of an email address are apparently valid according to symfony 1.4

Is there any valid reason why `sfValidatorEmail` doesn't accept dots in the local part of an email address?

Does the problem come from the webservice I'm using?

**UPDATE**

Just read the [RFC 3696](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696#section-3) and here's what it says:

> Without quotes, local-parts may consist
> of any combination of    alphabetic
> characters, digits, or any of the
> special characters
>
> ```
>   ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ?  ^ _ ` . { | } ~
> ```
>
> **period (".") may also appear, but
> may not be used to start or end the
>
> local part**, nor may two or more
> consecutive periods appear.

Comment: It seems you found a bug... maybe you sould report it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny enough the original 1.0 releases of Symfony had a more extendable email validator. You may read the code at http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.0/lib/validator/sfEmailValidator.class.php?rev=6991

There were two options for the built in regex pattern, the one you mentioned above and then Cal Henderson's. I believe Cal's might fit your needs better and you may easily use it with Symfony's Regex Validator. I pasted the regex pattern and the explaining comments below.

```
/* Cal Henderson: http://iamcal.com/publish/articles/php/parsing_email/pdf/
 * The long regular expression below is made by the following code
 * fragment:
 *
 *   $qtext = '[^\\x0d\\x22\\x5c\\x80-\\xff]';
 *   $dtext = '[^\\x0d\\x5b-\\x5d\\x80-\\xff]';
 *   $atom = '[^\\x00-\\x20\\x22\\x28\\x29\\x2c\\x2e\\x3a-\\x3c'
 *         . '\\x3e\\x40\\x5b-\\x5d\\x7f-\\xff]+';
 *   $quoted_pair = '\\x5c\\x00-\\x7f';
 *   $domain_literal = "\\x5b($dtext|$quoted_pair)*\\x5d";
 *   $quoted_string = "\\x22($qtext|$quoted_pair)*\\x22";
 *   $domain_ref = $atom;
 *   $sub_domain = "($domain_ref|$domain_literal)";
 *   $word = "($atom|$quoted_string)";
 *   $domain = "$sub_domain(\\x2e$sub_domain)*";
 *   $local_part = "$word(\\x2e$word)*";
 *   $addr_spec = "$local_part\\x40$domain";
 */

$re = '/^([^\\x00-\\x20\\x22\\x28\\x29\\x2c\\x2e\\x3a-\\x3c\\x3e\\x40\\x5b-'
     .'\\x5d\\x7f-\\xff]+|\\x22([^\\x0d\\x22\\x5c\\x80-\\xff]|\\x5c\\x00-'
     .'\\x7f)*\\x22)(\\x2e([^\\x00-\\x20\\x22\\x28\\x29\\x2c\\x2e\\x3a-'
     .'\\x3c\\x3e\\x40\\x5b-\\x5d\\x7f-\\xff]+|\\x22([^\\x0d\\x22\\x5c\\x80'
     .'-\\xff]|\\x5c\\x00-\\x7f)*\\x22))*\\x40([^\\x00-\\x20\\x22\\x28\\x29'
     .'\\x2c\\x2e\\x3a-\\x3c\\x3e\\x40\\x5b-\\x5d\\x7f-\\xff]+|\\x5b([^'
     .'\\x0d\\x5b-\\x5d\\x80-\\xff]|\\x5c\\x00-\\x7f)*\\x5d)(\\x2e([^\\x00-'
     .'\\x20\\x22\\x28\\x29\\x2c\\x2e\\x3a-\\x3c\\x3e\\x40\\x5b-\\x5d\\x7f-'
     .'\\xff]+|\\x5b([^\\x0d\\x5b-\\x5d\\x80-\\xff]|\\x5c\\x00-\\x7f)*'
     .'\\x5d))*$/'
;
```

I think it is also import to keep in mind that there are rare instances were a email address may not be RFC compliant, such as local intranet email addresses. Just a thought.

Comment: I believe you might actually want to check out this url, as Cal has updated his PHP email validator since. http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/